# how can i detect that type of line on image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, hough-transform

I want to detect that line on the image which i have drwan on it . I have mutiple images like that in which lines drawn on it with the label , L,R, F mean (Left , Right , Forward ) , this is the part of my Blind assistant application in which i want to train my model using different lines in the home that it guide the blind person to move in the home with voice command but first i have to detect that lines , I also try with hough transform  and canny but it only detect one  line and not work perfectly with image back ground .

[room image with line to detect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HoB5.jpg)

Comment: if u have the lines in specific color did u try masking those pixels first ? also how is the camera positioned ? can you show some real images ?

Comment: Is your line always in that exact color? IF yes try filtering in color space.